# Latest Chrome update fails to load XSLT document

Tags: javascript, xslt, xmlhttprequest

Since last Chrome update, when app tries to load an XSLT document it returns empty. I've found out that trying to do an XMLHttpRequest to load a XLST file if you try to return this.responseXML is empty while this.responseText works. Then you have to use a parser to convert it to 'application/xml'. It was working fine until latest update.

````
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url);
        if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
            try {
                req.responseType = 'msxml-document';
            }
            catch (e) { console.log('error');}
        }
        req.onload = function () {
            resolve(this.responseText);
            //resolve(this.responseXML); --this used to work
        }
        req.send();
    });
}```
````

Comment: What is the Content-type of the response?

Comment: adding req.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); seems to do the trick. By the way the error seems to happen only in Chrome, Edge is fine. Haven't tested in others

Comment: You should set the correct MIME type on the server when sending the response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Barmar. Will do.

Comment: Have you definitively determined that your exact code does work on the previous version of Chrome but not the current version?  If so, please [edit] your question and add the *exact* version numbers you've tested.  It would be very surprising to hear of browser changes in XSLT processing in 2023, so if you're correct, you should document this clearly for the benefit of future readers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
req.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
```

seems to do the trick. By the way the error seems to happen only in Chrome, Edge is fine. Haven't tested in others